# Synthesis of 1-iodo-4-nitrobenzene

Tags: experimental-chemistry, synthesis

I was trying to synthesize 1-iodo-4-nitrobenzene in the lab today – however, the appearance of my product really confused me.

At first, I added conc. sulfuric acid to water and 4-nitroaniline. 
This was followed by diazotising the amine sulfate with sodium nitrite and water. (This was done at temperatures of below $10\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$).

Then, I added the diazonium salt to a solution of $\ce{NaI}$ and water. A large plume/foam formed ($\ce{N2}$). After, I performed a filtration using a Büchner funnel. That’s where things went wrong.

I used water to wet the filter paper. I added in the iodonitrobenzene. A suckback occurred within a few seconds as the product was quite viscous. After resumption, the filtration went as planned. However, the product on the filter paper was a molten brown mush.

I tried to let it dry for a further 5 minutes but once turned off it remained a sludge.

Do you have any suggestions on how I could improve on this synthesis or maybe an idea of what went wrong?

Comment: 1) How quickly\slowly did you add the diazonium salt to the NaI solution?  2) Did you maintain the reaction temperature below 10C during the addition?  3) Did you keep the diazonium salt cooled while adding it?  4) After addition was complete, did you let the reaction stir at 10C until nitrogen evolution ceased and then let the reaction slowly warm to room temp?  [Here](http://myweb.brooklyn.liu.edu/swatson/Site/Laboratory_Manuals_files/Exp18.pdf) is a tested lab procedure, see where you differed.

Comment: Yes, I think a big issue was the fact that I didn't give enough time for the Nitrogen evolution to cease. You mention that I should have kept it at 10C even when the NaI was added. According to the manual I was following, this wasn't necessary.?

Comment: However, I didn't return it to the ice bath whenever I added the NaI. So, therefore, it didn't solidify. So, what was my brown sludge? Was it iodonitrobenzene, but in the wrong form?

Comment: Keeping the reaction cold during the addition is key.  If it warms up too much, the diazonium can react with itself to give colored by-products.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some things to focus on:

- How quickly\slowly did you add the diazonium salt to the NaI solution?
- Did you maintain the reaction temperature below 10°C during the entire addition?
- Did you also keep the diazonium salt cooled while adding it?
- After addition was complete, did you let the reaction stir at 10°C until nitrogen evolution ceased and then let the reaction slowly warm to room temp?

[Here](http://myweb.brooklyn.liu.edu/swatson/Site/Laboratory_Manuals_files/Exp18.pdf) is a tested lab procedure for the preparation of 4-iodonitrobenzene.  Compare it to your notes and see where you differed.

Keeping the reaction cold during the addition is key. If the diazonium salt warms up too much, the diazonium can react with itself ([coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azo_coupling)) to give colored by-products.  The diazonium ion can also eliminate nitrogen to generate the extremely reactive phenyl cation which will react with any nucleophile around, water for example (see page 6, the Mechanism section in this [reference](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/104103022/download/module7.pdf)).  Both pathways can  contaminate and reduce the yield of the desired product.

Comment: So the benzene ring of the diazonium could react with a Nitrogen triple bond? How could it ''react with itself''?   Would the Nitrogen dioxide act as a nucleophile on the nitrogen triple bond?

Comment: Yes, the terminal nitrogen in the diazonium can react with another activated aromatic compound (starting material, final product, by-product) to produce coupling products.  Your ring has a nitro group, so it is deactivated and less likely to couple.  More likely, your diazonium salt thermally decomposes (eliminates nitrogen) to generate the extremely reactive phenyl cation which will react with any nucleophile around, water for example.

Comment: @Maximilion  Feel free to ask follow-up questions. BTW, if the answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted, thanks!

Comment: Okay, so say if I decided to make 4-bromo or 4-nitrophenol or 4-nitrophenylhydrazine, would it be possible to use the Na- equivalent to NaI?

Comment: No, if you wanted to make 4-bromo-nitrobenzene from p-nitroaniline, you'd use CuBr ([Sandmeyer reaction](http://www.name-reaction.com/sandmeyer-reaction)).  Iodide is reactive enough to react directly with the diazonium ion, bromine and chlorine need a little help from copper.  Water is also reactive enough that generating the diazonium ion in the presence of excess water is a standard route to phenols.

Comment: Thanks ron . How is it that the arenediazonium salt will lose its N2 group in the presence of I- , even when cold? An elimination reaction? But if it's an elimination reaction, then why doesn't it then react with water when cold?

Comment: N2 is a very good leaving group so it is easily eliminated.  Still, for the nitrogen elimination to occur the diazonium must be warmed up.  If you keep the diazonium below 10C appreciable reaction won't occur.  Above this temperature the diazonium will eliminate nitrogen and react with iodide, hydroxide or whatever nucleophile is present.

Comment: Yes, but why I- in favour over water?

Comment: When you're trying to make an iodo compound you have a **lot** more iodide present than water when you warm up the diazonium.

Comment: Okay, in the synthesis of 1,3,5 tribromobenzene, how could I make the initial aniline reactant?

Comment: Are you asking about what conditions are required to react aniline with bromine in order to get 2,4,6-tribromoaniline?

Comment: It's okay, thank you. Would H2SO4 and Na2SO3 suffice in the formation of 4-nitrophenylhydrazine?

Comment: @Maximilion  Yes, that method was used for the synthesis of [4-nitrophenylhydrazine](http://nopr.niscair.res.in/bitstream/123456789/7404/1/IJEB%2048(3)%20265-268.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Wash the product (sludge) with 95% ethanol when filtering. The sludge is due to impurities.Your pure product should be light brown.